# Variadic templates and no values

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-programming, variadic-functions

Templates are good for programming template functions and classes, so we can use to shorten our code and let the compiler do some work for us.

In my case I want to make use of an template class eg.

```
template <typename T, typename G> class unicorn {
T value01;
G value02;   <- not used in ever instance of class unicorn
};
```

Is there a way, that the compiler make an instance with typename T = int for example and **if not used or specified**, version **without** typename G?

So that the result looks like:

```
unicorn <double, int>;

class unicorn {
double value01;
int value02;
};
```

And without Argument or specified typename G

```
unicorn <double>

class unicorn {
T value01;
// "not included in this instance"
};
```

Comment: Separate template for one type or maybe variadic template and std::tuple?

Comment: It seems like you are trying reinvent `std::tuple` with the caveat that you don't want more than two template parameters.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a finite number of use cases and don't want to dive into deep template metaprogramming then you can simply do template specialization

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename... Args>
struct Something;

template <typename T>
struct Something<T> {
  T a;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Something<T, U> {
  T a;
  U b;
};

int main() {
  __attribute__((unused)) Something<int> a;
  __attribute__((unused)) Something<int, double> b;

  return 0;
}
```

But for the general case I think an `std::tuple` might do the trick here.  Take a look at the following code

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename... Args>
class Something {
  std::tuple<Args...> tup;
};

int main() {
  __attribute__((unused)) Something<int> a;
  __attribute__((unused)) Something<int, double> b;

  return 0;
}
```

Of course you should be aware of some things like `std::ref` and the `get<>` function with a tuple.  You can also access the types of a template pack with some template metaprogramming.  I am not explaining that here because it might become a **really** long answer otherwise, if you would still like me to do so let me know in a comment below and I will try to explain it to you.

Comment: You should try making the specialisations generic.

Comment: @user2296177 sorry I dont think I follow, what do you mean?

Comment: Don't specialise for `<int>` and `<int, double>`, specialise for `<T>` and `<T, U>`. Example: the two type specialisation is `template<class T, class U> struct Something<T, U> { T a; U b; };`